# How to get heap dump from a remote server jvm?

Tags: jvm, heap-dump

How can I get aheap dump from a remote *JVM* which runs on linux with WL application server?

When I run locally on a windows machine I know how to get a dump. But, how do I get a dump from the user acceptance test server? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually SSH into it and do it

Comment: This question is off topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on Stack Overflow must be directly related to programming. Questions about remote server administration should be directed to [sf].

Answer (score 12):

You can use [JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/jconsole.html) to connect to the remote application server (it should be enabled in advance) and use the [HotSpotDiagnostic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html) MBean which allows taking a heap dump.
You can use [JConsole](https://openjdk.java.net/tools/svc/jconsole/) or [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) for invoking the MBean operation.
This [post](http://blog.bosch-si.com/categories/technology/2011/11/how-to-get-a-heap-dump-of-a-remote-machine-via-jmx/) by Mike Haller describes how to use this method with JVisualVM.

Answer (score 2):

Since its a *-nix system, and if you have the necessary privieleges, then it would be easy to connect to using *SSH* protocol:

- Connect to the remote machine:

  ```
  ssh user@remote-machine-ip-address
  ```
- Enter the user password once prompted for it (it should be the one for the user on the remote machine and not your current system user).
- Generate your heap dump using the `jmap` utility (JDK binaries path should be availble into your system PATH variable or use a full path to it):

  ```
  jmap -dump:format=b,file=cheap.bin <pid>
  ```

Comment: JRE does not have jmap utility only the JDK ships with jmap.

Comment: @anjanb thanks for the note, I have updated the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There are three steps:

1. ssh to your server

`ssh <your_user_name>@<remote_ip>`

2. jmap to trigger memory dump

`jmap -dump:format=b,file=<your_file_name> <your_jvm_pid>`

3. visualize the heap by jhat (here 512m is the size limit, you can set it depends on the leak's file size, like -J-Xmx2g)

`jhat -J-Xmx512m <your_file_name>`

`jhat -port 7401 <your_file_name>`

I write a blog to help analyze performance issue: [Performance Optimization](https://lihaimei.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/play-application-performance-optimization-2/)

Comment: When the server is running with just a JRE (and not a JDK), the `jmap` tool is not available on the server.

Comment: @MichielHaisma why are you focusing on this answer instead of [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27707332/2711488)? Shouldn’t you consider all answers before deciding to start a bounty?

Answer (score 1):

I've used Visual VM successfully for thread dumps and heap dumps, however, you don't list your JAVA version?

JAVA Visual VM is no longer shipped with JAVA, but can still be downloaded [here](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html) and it's still being maintained.  They just did a new minor release: **October 19, 2021: VisualVM 2.1.1 Released**.

> VisualVM has also been distributed in Oracle JDK 6~8 as Java VisualVM.
> It has been discontinued in Oracle JDK 9.

Here are steps for connecting to the VM from Dzone, [VisualVM: Monitoring Remote JVM Over SSH (JMX Or Not)](https://dzone.com/articles/visualvm-monitoring-remote-jvm)

For other alternatives, the Baeldung JAVA site, which has great information and tutorials, has [A Guide to Java Profilers](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers).